# accessing protected inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have to inherit protected members of base class and keep as protected in derived also. 
For-example: base class has set() and get() protected and they should be protected in derived also.
The problem is as they are protected in derived so how to access.

Actually I was trying to do this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Animal
{
protected:
    string name;
    void setName(string a){ name = a; }

    void getName(){ cout << name << endl; }


};
class Cat :public Animal
{
public:
      Cat(string dc){
        setName(dc);
}
       void printName(){ getName(); }
};
class Dog :public Animal
{
public:

    Dog(string dc2){
    setName(dc2);
    }

    void printName(){ getName(); }
};
int main()
{
    Cat c("Mano");
    c.printName();
    Dog d("Tommy");
    d.printName();

   system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want them to be protected in the derived class but the problem is that they are protected in the derived class? What are you actually trying to do? Maybe a small code sample would help.

Comment: If you make a member `protected` in base class why would you want it to be `public` in the derived class? If you want, make the member `public` in the base class itself!

Comment: I tried to set value using constructor and then I tried with a public function but this thing doesn't help. A lot of errors.

Comment: So you want protected functions that are not protected? What are you on about?

Comment: There is no problem public in derived. But I have to do this by protected This is my assignment.

Comment: NO they are protected in base and inherited as protected in derived also.

Comment: You may write public functions in the derived class that can access the protected functions of the derived class.

Comment: I might not be able to explain my question because I have just started it.

Comment: Try `type get_public() {  return get(); }` and `type set_public() { return set(); }`

Comment: Ok  Rikayan Bandyopadhyay I will follow you but if I am using a constructor. I mean that setting the value by constructor and then getting it using another public function. but what will then set() do.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://ideone.com/rFE2ns